# How to use names when importing csv data into matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, genfromtxt

I cannot figure out how to use the "names" in matplotlib when plotting data returned by numpy.genfromtxt command.
Scenario:
1. I have a file with columns headers and rows of values
2. I don't know the column headers beforehand--they are generated programmatically and may change during the program run
3. I need to read the data AND the column headers, plot them and produce a corresponding legend.

I can read the data columns with their names with:

```
dataArray = numpy.genfromtxt('myData.csv', delimiter = ',', names = True)
```

and then plot them with

```
matplotlib.plot.plot(dataArray)
matplotlib.plot.show()
```

but how do I produce a suitable legend? I thought the legend command with no parameters would suffice (e.g. `matplotlib.plot.legend()`) but that is not the case. I get an error instead:

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py:4601: UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
  warnings.warn("No labeled objects found. "

In other words:where do those "names" go and how can I retrieve them? Multiple searches on google, matplotlib site, and numy site produced no results.

Comment: Can you show an extract of your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a `label=..` keyword in the `plot` function for each line you want to plot, as matplotlib does not automatically detect names from a numpy structured array (you can also use pandas, which does this, see below).

Say for example you data look like this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

myDatacsv = StringIO("""a, b, c
1, 2, 3
2, 3, 4
3, 4, 5""")
```

Reading them with `numpy.genfromtxt` produces a structured array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> dataArray = np.genfromtxt(myDatacsv, delimiter = ',', names = True)
>>> dataArray
array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (2.0, 3.0, 4.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

(In your case there will be `"myData.csv"` instead of `myDatacsv` off course, this is just to make the example)
Now you can loop over the column names and plot each of them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
for col_name in dataArray.dtype.names:
    plt.plot(dataArray[col_name], label=col_name)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

---

This will generate a figure like this:

[image]

With pandas, this will produce the same figure (automatically plotting all columns of the dataframe and adding it to a legend):

```
import pandas as pd

# one of the following will do (reading it with pandas, or converting 
# from the numpy array to pandas dataframe)
data_df = pd.read_csv(myDatacsv)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(dataArray)

data_df.plot()
```

For more information about pandas, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Thanks! the dtype bit is what I was missing. I didn't know that's where the columns' names end up. And thanks also for the pointer to pandas. I'll check it out.